# @setter: Pass and set all class properties in one method

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, singleton, session-variables

I have a need for a Singleton class instance that is accessible from anywhere has certain session variables that can change.

```
class MySingletonClass(Singleton):

    @property
    def session(self):
        return self

    @session.setter
    def session(self, d):
        self.name = d['name']
        self.id = d['id']
        self.mode = d['mode']

experiment = MySingletonClass()
```

This can then be imported and variables set as such

```
from core import experiment
experiment.session={'name':'my_exp_name', 'mode':'my_mode', 'id':"1234"}
```

I want to pass them all in one but instead of a dictionary as I have currently, as a function argument. So something like the following:

```
experiment.set_session('my_exp_name', 'my_mode','1234')
```

My current property approach prevents that from doing. I do want to maintain each session variable as a property in and of itself but I also want to set them all together since there are plenty of session variables. Just dont like the passing it as a dictionary.

I would appreciate if someone can help with the design and/or make it better. I need an instance of a class that has a bunch of variables that can be accessed from anywhere. The variables inside the class can change but not the class instance itself. And I need a better was to set all the variables in one go (preferably a method instead of setting the dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a bunch of read-only properties, but with a single "setter".

```
class MySingletonClass(Singleton):
    @property
    def session(self):
        return self

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def mode(self):
        return self._mode

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    def set_session(self, name, mode, id):
        self._name = name
        self._mode = mode
        self._id = id
```

You can reduce some of the boilerplate with a custom descriptor:

```
class Field:
    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return getattr(obj, self.name)

    def __set_name__(self, obj, name):
        self.name = "_" + name


class MySingletonClass(Singleton):
    name = Field()
    mode = Field()
    id = Field()

    def set_session(self, name, mode, id):
        self._name = name
        self._mode = mode
        self._id = id
```

Comment: how does the Field() work. Am I expected to pass name of type Field to the set_session method or am I passing a string

Comment: `__set_name__` is called automatically when the class is created, so that you don' have to write `name = Field("name")`. The name of the attribute that the descriptor is assigned to is passed as an argument.

Comment: Fixed the definition of `__set_name__` to prepend a `_` to the name, so that the later call to `getattr` doesn't result in infinite recursion.